# Совершится или Свершится - В чем разница?

Tags: выбор-слов, значение-слов

Корректно ли говорить

> Подождем пока это событие не совершится?

или корректно будет только

> Подождем пока это событие не свершится?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Правильно: **Подождем, пока это событие **не произойдет**.**

Это нейтральный стиль речи, другие варианты не подходят.

Книжный стиль: совершиться. Высокий стиль: свершиться.

**Из словаря:**

**СОВЕРШИТЬСЯ**, св. Произойти, осуществиться. Совершилось важное событие. Какая совершилась в нём перемена! <Совершаться, -ается; нсв. Такое совершается впервые! Совершение (см.).

**СВЕРШИТЬСЯ**, св. Высок. Произойти, осуществиться. Свершилась казнь. Свершилось чудо. Свершилась мечта. Свершился сон. <Свершаться, -ается; нсв.

Comment: Все-таки с событием лучше употреблять "произойти". "Совершилось важное событие" ещё возможно. Но вот скажем, "совершился несчастный случай" уже не корректно, хотя "совершилось чудо" вполне работает. Возможно потому что чудо совершает кто-то, а несчастный случай происходит сам по себе.
 .

Answer (score 2):

Изначально, оба слова являются разными вариантами преобразования из церковнославянского `съврьшити`, где ъ в приставке `съ-` обозначало звук [ə]. Такое можно увидеть, например, в современном болгарском.

В русском языке постепенный уход от традиций церковнославянского и старославянского привел к необходимости убрать твердый знак из таких слов. Это привело к формированию двух вариантов написания и чтения `съ-`:

- если твердый знак просто опускался, то при чтении пропадал и гласный звук: получалась приставка `с-` (`свершить`, `сбор`);
- если твердый знак заменялся на о, то при чтении сохранялся гласный звук [ə]: получалась приставка `со-` (`совершить`, `собор`).

Со временем эти слова стали считаться независимыми. В случае с `свершить` выделяется приставка `c-` и корень `-верш-`, в то время как в `совершить` корнем считается `соверш-` как в слове `совершенный`.

В современном языке слова являются синонимами—используйте какой вам угодно. Если посмотреть по [статистике](https://books.google.com/ngrams) использования, то вариант с гласной был более популярен ранее, но сейчас разницы особой нет:

[image: Статистика употребления в соответствии с данными Google Books]

Если чуть более глубоко копнуть, то я бы сказал, что два варианта начинают разделять два разных смысла исходного слова. `Съврьшити` одновременно обозначало и законченность, и совершенство. И хотя эти понятия крайне близки, на мой взгляд, `свершить` имеет более выраженный оттенок завершенности/окончания, а `совершить`—идеальности/совершенности.